# Find the minimal algebra and $σ$ algebra

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, measure-theory

Let $A$,$B$,$C$ be three arbitrary sets since they are all subsets of $Ω$. Find the minimal algebra and  $σ$ algebra generated by these three sets.

I did not understand this question. How can I approach can you help me please.

Comment: Find an ($\sigma$) algebra $\mathcal A\subset\wp(\Omega)$ that contains the sets $A,B,C$ and is minimal in the sense that it will be contained in *any* ($\sigma$) algebra that contains the sets $A,B,C$. It comes to allowing sets to belong to $\mathcal A$ only if this is unavoidable. E.g. set $A^c$ cannot be missed because a ($\sigma$) algebra is closed under complements. Do you understand the question now?

Comment: Thank you for helping, how can I find can you help me @drhab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal A$ denotes the minimal algebra on $\Omega$ with $A,B,C\in\mathcal A$ then every set of the form $U\cap V\cap W$ where $U\in\{A,A^c\}$, $V\in\{B,B^c\}$ and $W\in\{C,C^c\}$ will be an element of $\mathcal A$. This because an algebra is closed under complements and intersections. There are at most $8$ distinct sets of that form.

Secondly note that also every union of these sets $U\cap V\cap W$ will be an element of $\mathcal A$. This because an algebra is closed under finite unions. It can be proved that the collection of these unions is an algebra, so this collection coincides with $\mathcal A$.

Also it can be shown that algebra $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (this because $\mathcal A$ contains a *finite* number of sets), so $\mathcal A$  will also function as minimal $\sigma$-algebra containing $A,B,C$.